# Using Parent Directories in Manifest.in

Tags: python

I know MANIFEST.in recognizes relative paths. However, can I use relative paths that point to directories outside of the project?

For example:

```
/home
    /random_dir
    /python_project
        MANIFEST.in
        setup.py
        /packages
```

And then inside MANIFEST.in

```
graft ../random_dir/
```

If not, is there an alternative way of including such directories other than just copying and pasting the directory into the project?

Answer (score 4):

I tested it for you . It seem to not want to go any lower than the project root.

Use a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) instead. Depending on the data and your workstructure, a [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) could solve your situation better.